# Is there a way to differentiate between someone replying to you, and someone mentioning you directly on Twitter using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm working on a bot that does jobs for Twitter users. They're supposed to request help by mentioning my bot like "@bot" with any other options in the text, optional.

Problem is, Twitter seems to consider directly @'ing someone in a new standalone tweet like "@jake hey" and replying to a tweet that user @jake made, with "hey" to be the exact same thing. If I check the full_text field for each status on tweepy, they both appear as "@jake hey". My bot needs a user supplied video to do its job. So if my bot were to reply to someone with a finished job, someone could reply to my bot with a video as a reaction to it, perhaps a video where someone says "Thank you!", my bot would confuse that as someone trying to request it to analyze that video for it. I need to prevent this so I don't reply to that user who didn't actually want to submit the video to my bot. I can't seem to find a way to differentiate between these two tweet examples, they seem to be the same under the hood. I hope I explained it soundly enough. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: If the Tweet object contains an `in_reply_to` field then it is a reply to another Tweet; otherwise, it's a "new" Tweet. So, if `in_reply_to_status_id` is null, you can assume it's a command to your bot to do something, otherwise, it's a follow up to something your bot posted before.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my bot still helps users even if they are replying to someone else. Two examples where it does that: 1. if they are replying to someone else who posted the video they want my bot to analyze 2. if they are in a situation where they want to show someone else what my bot does, they could @ my bot on Twitter and request it in the midst of a reply chain

Comment: You could check that the post is in reply to your bot user ID directly, then - it’s another field in the Tweet.

Comment: Late reply but, the routes as far as I can see are:

1. they @ my bot not replying to anything (Easy for me to handle no issue)

2. they @ my bot replying to a video or posting a video, my bot was never in this reply chain before (easy to handle again, no issue)

3. Situation #2, but this time they reply to me or to someone who has replied to me with a vid in chain, my bot detects that as a not completed job and tends to it although they never directly mentioned me, twitter puts my username in the full_text status body field. This is the one I am trying to eliminate.

Comment: Unfortunately, checking if their post is in direct reply doesn't help because if it is, they could still have @'d my bot. Or maybe not, yet still replied to me. Then, they could have been much further down the reply chain, and @'d me while replying to joe shmoe's video tweet, and there is no reason why my bot shouldn't service that request. 

Appreciate the try tho

Comment: Basically, whether or not they are in direct reply to one of my bots tweets doesn't supply anything useful to determine whether or not it is a valid job or not. Like I can't use the fact that they replied to my bot as like "Do not service this person just because they directly replied to me, JUST in case its a false positive and they only wanted to reply with a video for a reason like I gave in the original stackoverflow post